# Total EST Time for Download

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Using the event below how would one show the total time left for a file 
    transfer the progress bar is working fine but I would like to show the amount of 
    time left as well if that is possible

```
 Private Sub onTransferProgress(ByVal source As String, ByVal destination As String, ByVal transferredBytes As Integer, ByVal totalBytes As Integer, ByVal message As String) Handles transfer.onTransferProgress
    Dim totalbytess As Long = transferredBytes / 1024
    Dim mtotalbytes As Long = totalbytess / 1024
    Dim status As String = ""
    status = status & " Transfering Files - transferred: " & source & " to " & destination


    Me.ProgressBar1.Value = transferredBytes
    status = status & "Transferring.. " & (ProgressBar1.Value / 1024).ToString()

    Me.tbStatus.Text = status
    lblWorking.Text = message
    lblWorking.Visible = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many progress bars these days don't do this because the information isn't always reliable. Past performance doesn't guarantee future results.

But if you want to, outside of this method, upon the start of download you'll want to store the current time. Then in this method count the number of seconds that have elapsed since that time. Then you'll just have some simple math. `transferredBytes` took X seconds so `totalbytess` should take Y seconds.

So if you you're transferring 10MB (10485760 bytes) and you've recieved 2MB (2097152 bytes) and 20 seconds has elapsed you're transferring at a rate of 104,857.6 bytes/sec. You have 8MB (8388608) left so 8388608 divided by 104,857.6 is 80 seconds.

```
Dim remainingBytes = totalbytess - mtotalbytes
Dim currentTransferRate = mtotalbytes / <your time calculation here>
Dim remainingSeconds = remainingBytes / currentTransferRate
```